# Why is Notepad++ Adding Lines

Tags: html, notepad++, filezilla

I am working on a site between a few computers. Every time I pull the latest file for the page I've been working on from the host and open it up on a new computer in Notepad++ there are new carriage returns in between each line. If I were to upload and pull down from a new workstation there would be even more line breaks.

Why is this happening?

Sorry if this has been covered, but in all my searches I didn't find this same problem.

Comment: does this happen if you use another editor?

Comment: no, opening in Notepad shows it just as I left it.

Comment: Check Notepad++ settings. Make sure files default to UTF-8 encoding and check for something like "Insert line breaks..."

Comment: Is set to UTF-8, don't see any setting regarding inserting line breaks.

Comment: OK, after some more research it seems to be a FileZilla setting, and not a Notepad++ setting. Don't know quite yet how to fix it, but if i download the file using cPanel the problem isn't there...